# NSURLConnection and Blocks

Tags: objective-c, nsurlconnection, block

My callbacks aren't being called. I'm not that familiar with dispatch_async so any thoughts? Point being, I never see a Response.

```
+ (void)asyncRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
         success:(void(^)(NSData *, NSURLResponse *))successBlock_ 
         failure:(void(^)(NSData *, NSError *))failureBlock_ 
{
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{

    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    NSURLResponse *response = nil;
    NSError *error = nil;

    NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                                         returningResponse:&response 
                                                     error:&error];

    NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"-----------------result %@", result);

    if (error) {
        failureBlock_(data,error);
    } else {
        successBlock_(data,response);
    }
    [pool release];
});
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't be testing the `error` variable. You should be testing the `data` variable, and only looking at `error` if `data` is nil. It's perfectly legal for the method to return a valid `data`, and then return a garbage pointer in `error`.

Comment: Are you getting as far as the Log message? And is the app crashing?

Comment: Kevin thanks, I made the change.

Comment: Firoze, the log message never even prints so I suspect it's either taking a really really long time to return a response or on a different different thread. dispatch_async is tripping me up a little bit, but from what I read, what NSOperation is based on.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you implementing your own sendAsync method?

You should look into using the provided one instead, [NSURLClassReference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsurlconnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001697-DontLinkElementID_1)

**EDIT**

Assuming you're developing for OSX, not iOS. Evidently this method is not available for iOS.

Comment: I'm writing a static library that can be used for either. Rewriting sendAsync isn't the issue though.